# Parallel Download from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I was reading this [blog entry](http://bcbio.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/parallel-upload-to-amazon-s3-with-python-boto-and-multiprocessing/) about parallel upload into S3 using boto. Near the end it suggests a few tools for downloading using multiple connections (axel, aria2, and lftp). How can I go about using these with S3? I don't know how to pass the authentication keys to Amazon to access the file. I can, however, make the file public temporarily, but this solution is non-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

[Generate a signed url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628984/135625) using the AWS API and use that for your downloads. Only someone with the signed url (which expires in the given timeout) can download the file.